# SQLite Execute query from joined Tables

Tags: sqlite, flask, inner-join, cs50

I am struggling with my final project. I need to join 2 Tables "book" and "idlist" and execute the values in index.html. 
Here is python and html code (also [idlist Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsjhR.jpg)[book Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3svJp.jpg)). 
If someone knows where is a mistake, I will be grateful!

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
    """Show reading list"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        # Execute list joining "book" and "idlist" tables
        list = db.execute("SELECT Title1, Status, LastUpdate, Author, Year, Country, Language FROM idlist INNER JOIN book on idlist.Title1=book.Title WHERE id=:id",
                          id=session["user_id"])
        # If the user has no list yet
        if not list:
            el = {'Title1': "No", 'Author': "No", 'Year': "No", 'Country': "No", 'Language': "No", 'Status': "No", 'LastUpdate': "No"}
            return render_template("index.html")
        else:
            return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html")
```

html should execute the values from the joined tables

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Last update</th>
            </tr>
                {% for el in list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Title1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Author }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Year }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Country }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Language }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Status }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.LastUpdate }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the error while I login with user id 16:
RuntimeError: near "update": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT Title, Status, update, Author, Year, Country, Language FROM idlist INNER JOIN book on idlis
t.Title=book.Title WHERE id=16']

Comment: [Hint, hint](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;) Besides: the links do not work.

Comment: Danke or thanks! @MarkusWMahlberg

Comment: The `render_template()` function in Flask needs some data, you are not passing any data. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: By the way, you can determine which HTTP method a function is bound to directly in the `@route` decorator (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods). Writing several dedicated functions is better than writing one catch-all function and using `if request.method == "GET":` etc. inside of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links @Tomalak. How I can say "go to "/" and get all the values from the joined tables with?"  return redirect("/")?

Comment: @Tomalak I think that the problem is with query - because the error message is the same: RuntimeError: near "update": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT Title, Status, update, Author, Year, Country, Language FROM idlist INNER JOIN book on idlis t.Title=book.Title WHERE id=16']

Comment: Oh, yes. `UPDATE` is a reserved word in SQL (just like `SELECT`). Avoid calling your table columns like reserved words. It's best to rename the column. `LastUpdate` would be a fine name.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks I have changed to LastUpdate. Good point! The program returns no errors but unfortunately it exists with zeros for each column. Either it could not generate “list” or some problems in html.

Comment: Read comment #4 again. You're not doing that.

Comment: @Tomalak do you mean using return render_template() is totally wrong or that I need to pass “list” into it?

Comment: You need to pass `list` into it. Inside `render_template()`, only variables are known that you have explicitly passed. It can't see any of the variables you're using in your other code.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks a lot for your help! I will try it!

Comment: @Tomalak It works! Finally! I am so grateful!

Comment: Nice! And you've figured it out on your own! :) If you post an answer containing your modified code along with a paragraph about what was the issue, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Tomalak I have done!

Answer (score 1):

My program should join 2 Tables "book" and "idlist" and execute the values in index.html. 
The main issue was in the wrong use of the "render_template()" more presisely that I haven't passed any data into it. As I needed to express my "list" in html form, the right use would be "return render_template("index.html", list=list)"

Below is the solution:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
    """Show reading list"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        quote1 = db.execute("SELECT quote FROM quotes ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1")
        # Execute list joining "book" and "idlist" tables
        list = db.execute("SELECT Title1, Status, LastUpdate, Author, Year, Country, Language FROM idlist INNER JOIN book on idlist.Title1=book.Title WHERE id=:id",
                          id=session["user_id"])
        # If the user has no list yet
        if not list:
            el = {'Title1': "No", 'Author': "No", 'Year': "No", 'Country': "No", 'Language': "No", 'Status': "No", 'LastUpdate': "No"}
        return render_template("index.html", yourquote=quote1[0]["quote"])

    return render_template("index.html")
```

Here is html form:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Last update</th>
            </tr>
                {% for el in list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Title1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Author }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Year }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Country }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Language }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.Status }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ el.LastUpdate }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <tr>
            <p> </p>

        </tr>
        <a class="card-header" href="/"><span class="blue">Inspire yourself</span></a>
         <tr>
            <p> </p>

        </tr>
        <a class="card-title"><span class="grey"><p>{{ yourquote }}</p></span></a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can do `if if not list: el = { ... }` without `else`, since you use `return render_template(...)` in both cases. This line can therefore be moved outside the `if`.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks! Now is better, isn't it?

Comment: I can see that you pass in `yourquote`, but you don't seem to pass in `list`.